# After file upload, response path not updating in live server using node js & sequelize update method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Node version - 10.15.3
Sequelize version - 5.21.3

Up to Execute 4 working properly.After that the error occurred.

```
businesstest.post('/test-update/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
var paramID = req.params.id;
var ValidImageTypes = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
if (req.files) {
    var in_array = require('in_array');
    if (!in_array(req.files.logo.mimetype, ValidImageTypes, true)) {
        return callback({ code: 500, status: 'error', message: "Image extension not valid.", errors: { avater: "Please provide jpg/jpeg/png type file." } });
    }
}
console.log("Execute 1");
//===Image upload and update in db
var filePath = '/images/test/' + parseInt(paramID) + '/';
var fileUploadResp = await fileLib.awaitUploadFile(req.files.logo, filePath, req.files.logo.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'));
console.log("Execute 2");
if (fileUploadResp.status !== 'success') {
    return callback({ code: 500, status: 'error', message: 'File not uploaded!' });
}
console.log("Execute 3");
var updateData = {};
updateData['description'] = fileUploadResp.filename;
console.log(fileUploadResp);
console.log("Execute 4");
try {
    var updatedResp = await Testmodel.update(updateData, { where: { id: parseInt(paramID) } });
    console.log("Execute 5");
    if (updatedResp) {
        return res.status(200).json(fileUploadResp);
    }
} catch (e) {
    if (Settings.DEBUG_MODE) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    return res.status(500).json({ code: 500, status: 'error', message: 'Please check your internet connection!', data: {} });
}
```

});

[Tested through postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttMO9.png)